# Copy multiple pdf files into another directory and every file creating folder with its name

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory, filenames

I have a folder with around 150 pdf files. I would like to create folders in the name of the 150 files. After that I would like the pdf file to be moved to its respective folder.Can its possible in cmd or any exe file?
Example
E:\
       |______ abc.pdf
       |______ cde.pdf
       |______ efg.pdf
F:\backup\
|______ abc
        |____abc.pdf
|______ cde
       |____cde.pdf
|______ efg
      |____efg.pdf

Comment: Could you share an example of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not tested

```
@echo off

set "source=E:\"
set "target=F:\bckp"

for %%a in ("%source%*pdf") do (
    mkdir "%target%\%%~na"
    copy "%%~fa" "%target%\%%~na"
)
```

Comment: That will almost work, but `"%target%\%%~na"` needs to be `"%target%\%%~nxa"` or you'll lose the .pdf

Comment: @Tzalumen - thanks for the note , but in the example from the OP the name of the folders should be without `.pdf` .The full path to the files is taken with `%%~fa` - which will include also the extension

Comment: Oh, you're right, I missed something. The way copy works (fullpath to fullpath), you'd need
`copy "%%~fa" "%target%\%%~na\%%~nxa"`
which for a file with a full path of E:\foo.pdf will resolve to `copy "E:\foo.pdf" "F:\bckp\foo\foo.pdf"` while the code in your example would resolve to `copy "E:\foo.pdf" "F:\bckp\foo"` resulting in both a file and a folder in F:\bckp named foo.

Comment: @ npocmaka I should point out, the syntax of `COPY C:\foo.bar C:\baz\foo.bar` is required for `COPY`, but not for `MOVE`. Your code is correct for `MOVE`.